# Emacs use variable if set in grep-find

Tags: emacs, grep, elisp

I'm looking for a way to always launch my grep-find from a specific location if a variable is set. I'm thinking something like:

1. Launch emacs from /home/user/mycode/
2. Open file(s) in e.g. /home/user/mycode/a/b/c/
3. Run grep-find from /home/user/mycode/

I know that it works if I first open the /home/user/mycode/ directory and then runs grep-find but I want this to be stored as a variable instead. (If the variable is not set it would be fine to simply do the search from the current location)

My grep-find looks like this:

```
(setq grep-find-command "find . '(' -type f ')' -print0 | xargs -0 -e grep -n -e ")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you would benefit from projectile.

It does just what you need.  It has a recursive grep command that it launches from parent directory (it can use also git-grep or ag, a lot faster than grep), and it offers a lot more.  You can work with multiple projects at once (projectile is smart that way).

You can look at projectile here: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile

It is available via MELPA

If you do not want to use it (or similar alternatives), I would advise wrapping your recursive grep command in a custom function like this:

```
(defun rgrep-at-repo-base (...)
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (while (and (not (file-exists-p ".git/"))
                (not (equal "/" default-directory)))
      (cd ".."))
    (rgrep ...)))
```

Where you should change the logic for finding your code base from current directory (example works for git repos) and set the arguments you need (if any)

Comment: Thanks! I think projectile is what I want. I was trying to add a .projectile file in my project root including the following content: "-*.txt" (ignore all .txt files in searches) but it doesn't seem to recognize it. Do I have to specify somewhere that the .projectfile shall be used?